# onsubmit call function on safari not working?

Tags: javascript, safari

Work perfectly on Chrome and firefox , but nothing on safari ?

```
<form onsubmit="Toaster()" method="post" class="std" enctype="multipart/form-data">

function Toaster(){
  var loading_screen = pleaseWait({
      logo: "assets/images/pathgather.png",
      backgroundColor: '#f46d3b',
      loadingHtml: ""
    });
  }
```

Comment: What is the "pleaseWait"  doing?

Comment: its a loader it work perfectly on chrome and firefox

Comment: I only have your word for that. How can we know or test your issue if you do not post it or at least a link to the site where you found it?